# Wifi Not Found Fedora 33

Tags: fedora, wifi, drivers

I upgraded my Fedora 32 to Fedora 33 and lost my WiFi. Says Wifi Adapters Not Found

```
bash-5.0# lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 [8086:24fd] (rev 78)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265 [8086:1010]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi, wl

# dmesg | egrep -i "iwl|firmware"
[    0.184654] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.516378] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    3.694241] [Firmware Bug]: No valid trip found
[    5.654544] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin (v1.4)
[   26.770862] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   26.773171] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8265-36.ucode failed with error -2
[   26.773185] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8265-35.ucode failed with error -2
[   26.773196] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8265-34.ucode failed with error -2
[   26.773224] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8265-33.ucode failed with error -2
[   26.773243] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8265-32.ucode failed with error -2
[   26.773258] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8265-31.ucode failed with error -2
[   26.773269] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8265-30.ucode failed with error -2
[   26.773279] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8265-29.ucode failed with error -2
[   26.773291] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8265-28.ucode failed with error -2
[   26.773302] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8265-27.ucode failed with error -2
[   26.773313] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8265-26.ucode failed with error -2
[   26.773324] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8265-25.ucode failed with error -2
[   26.773335] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8265-24.ucode failed with error -2
[   26.773346] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8265-23.ucode failed with error -2
[   26.901477] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 22.361476.0 8265-22.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[   26.901559] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwl-debug-yoyo.bin failed with error -2
[   27.172729] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8265, REV=0x230
[   27.231103] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: base HW address: d4:6d:6d:9e:a0:52
[   27.310244] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[   27.987541] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[   28.054367] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-12-16.sfi
[   28.398831] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[   29.614273] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[   29.614558] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1590392 usecs
[   29.661485] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.1 build 50 week 12 2019
[  488.919600] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
[  506.024996] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
```

I have tried installing `broadcom-wl` but seems not to work. I am not sure what to do.

Comment: please post the output of `dmesg | egrep -i "iwl|firmware"`. The driver you tried to install will not work for your Intel HW.

Comment: I have edited the query to show the result as requested

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `iwlwifi-8265-36.ucode`.

`dnf install iwl7260-firmware`

should fix it for you.